# Connecting ordinary hard disk as external usb hard disk to laptop via scsi to usb convertor

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, scsi

I am in need of using an internal hard disk of a computer, dismantled from the original PC and connect to my laptop via SCSI to USB convertor. I basically want to use it as an external usb hard disk for my laptop to do some data back up. I have the usb to scsi convertor which came with an usb external hard disk that i purchased. I have connected the set up but the hard disk is not detected on the laptop. I'd appreciate some suggestions on how to make it work.

Comment: You probably should get a generic converter, vs using one salvaged from a pre-packaged unit.  The generic converter would be designed to handle any drive (within reason), while the pre-packaged converter is apt to be limited to a small number of drive types.

Comment: @DanH : Assuming that the convertor is ok, is there any other possible things to be done to make it work. I have a seagate hard disk and the convertor came with a freeagent hard disk. hope something else could be missing.

Comment: There are lots of different [SCSI interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI#Parallel_SCSI) exactly which one is the disk and exactly which one is the convertor? Alternatively, post exact model numbers for both.

Comment: Of course, everything that needs power is getting it, right?  If the HDD is 3.5", are you using some sort of external power supply?  And the HDD is powered up and spinning *before* you make the USB connection to the PC?